# `net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit` parameter is not added in container network namespace

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, kernel, docker-swarm

I'm trying to set `net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit` parameter inside container but it gives me error:

> ```
> open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_challenge_ack_limit: no such file or directory: unknown
> ```

My kernel version is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux controller 4.14.240-pc64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 23 09:53:06 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My docker version:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.4, build 20.10.4
```

Looks like Docker is not able to add this parameter in container namespace.

On host, I can see this parameter using `sysctl -a` command and I am able to update it as well, but problem is that this parameter is not part of container namespace.

I googled a bit and found that such issue comes when this parameter is not namespaced. Now I m not sure why this parameter is not name spaced and whether this is an issue in Docker or in the kernel.

Comment: If it's not a namespaced parameter, then there is only one value of it across the entire system.  You can't set it from a container (it would affect all other containers and non-container processes).  Use `sudo sysctl` on your host system instead.

Comment: it did not help. i have tried to bringup container wiht both root and non root user and this tcp parameter does not get added to network namespace